# Vector calculation seems unable to compute angle between two planes

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, solid-geometry

**Problem**

> Given the cube $ABCD.EFGH$. The point $M$ is on the edge $AD$ such that $|AM|=2|MD|$. Calculate the tangent of the angle between the planes $BCF$ and $BGM$.
>
> (A) $3 \sqrt 2$
>
> (B) $2 \sqrt 2$
>
> (C) $\frac{3}{2} \sqrt 2$
>
> (D) $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt 2$
>
> (E) $\sqrt 2$

**Attempts**

Denote each point as $A=(0,0,0)$, $B=(1,0,0)$, $C=(1,1,0)$, $D=(0,1,0)$, $E=(0,0,1)$, $F=(1,0,1)$, $G=(1,1,1)$, $H=(0,1,1)$, and $M=(0,\frac{2}{3},0)$. Using an [online software](https://www.mathepower.com/en/transformplaneequations.php) to compute plane equation given through three points, I arrived at $BCF \equiv x=1$ and $BGM \equiv -\frac{2}{3}x-y+z=-\frac{2}{3}$. Using [dihedral angle formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DihedralAngle.html), I got $\frac{\sqrt{22}}{11}$, which makes me unable to choose the answer from given the options above.

Without relying much on Euclidean geometry, how can I calculate this distance problem of solid geometry?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that you've labeled the points of the cube in the wrong order?  Is there a diagram that was included with this question when it was asked?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The question does not have a diagram. I labeled ABCD on bottom of the cube, the A is starting point then proceed to label other points in counterclockwise. The labeling of EFGH also proceeds in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value that you've got, $\frac{\sqrt{22}}{11}$ is the cosine of the angle.
Then $$\tan\alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\alpha}}{\cos\alpha}\\=\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{22}{11^2}}}{\frac{\sqrt{22}}{11}}=\sqrt{\frac{99}{22}}=3\frac1{\sqrt{2}}=\frac32\sqrt 2$$

Comment: I thought the "tangent" is just an another term for "intersect". I did not know it meant to find the value of the $\tan{\alpha}$. Thank you very much.